# How do I flush the DNS cache in Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: mac, dns, cache

I have done some changes to `/private/etc/hosts` on my mac and need to flush the DNS cache.

Previously been using `lookupd -flushcache` on Mac OS X 10.4 to do this successfully. However something seems to have changed in Mac OS X 10.5, cause the `lookupd` command doesn't seem to exist? How do you flush the DNS cache in Mac OS X 10.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on [Mac OS X Hints](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071027100807321) =)

> I primarily work with web servers, and I use `lookupd -flushcache` all of the time to clear my DNS cache.
>
> This morning was moving some websites around using my newly-upgraded Mac, and I went to flush my DNS cache with `lookupd` and I got a command not found error. It seems that `lookupd` has been removed in 10.5 and replaced with `dscacheutil`.
>
> So now I can flush my DNS cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache`.